# Programmatically play youtube video on mobile device

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, youtube

I'm struggling with playing youtube video after a countdown from javascript. It is working in chrome but not in chrome on android devices.
The error is: "API can only be initiated by a user gesture".
The same problem arises with an html5 video, but in this case I was able to solve the issue thanks to [andreybavt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2112409/andreybavt) answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32424775/failed-to-execute-play-on-htmlmediaelement-api-can-only-be-initiated-by-a-u) question.

Comment: Isn't it restricted by youtube? I don't know the situation, but couldn't you use youtube-dl and stream from you server?

Comment: No I can't. For my use case I have to stream directly from youtube